# Can I use a third party view engine for Razor Pages?

Tags: asp.net, razor, blazor, razor-pages, spark-view-engine

Although it is called **Razor** Pages for a reason I'm just wondering if it is possible to use a different view engine, say Spark Engine or any other View Engine you can think of.

I also wonder the same thing for Blazor.

Edit: This question was previously closed because it was thought that I was looking for recommendations. I'm not looking for recommendations, I want to learn if it is possible to change the view engine of a Razor Pages project.

Comment: What would be the use-case?  They all have their own syntax. And for Blazor, how do you imagine the C# integration?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm not conserned about the use case, I'm just wondering if it would work. I don't get your second question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a microsoft project that changes the rendering engine to use blazor for native platform apps.
It is in very early stage, but shows the possibilities.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-blazor-bindings/

I believe it’s completly possible, but very complicated, considering that you are going to need rewrite all the bindings and connections that blazor offers.